# Global variable in Google App engine Nodejs Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-app-engine, puppeteer

This code works in local, but when I deploy to Google App Engine I got the error "Browser var is not defined". How can I define globally the browser variable in better way?
My goal is to launch puppeteer browser at startup and use the same instance to open a new webpage for each HTTP request.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const express   = require('express');
const fs        = require('fs');
var port        = process.env.PORT || 80;
const app       = express();

app.get('/request',  async (req, res, next) => {

  console.log(browser)

   //using browser var here   <---
   // UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: browser is not defined

});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Listening on PORT: ', port)
  setup()
});

const setup = async function(){

  console.log("Initializing Puppeteer...")
  global.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: [
      '--no-sandbox', 
      '--disable-setuid-sandbox', 
      '--disable-dev-shm-usage=true',
      '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas=true',
      '--disable-gpu', 
      ]
  });

browser.on('disconnected', setup);

console.log(`Started Puppeteer with pid ${browser.process().pid}`);
}
```

**app.yml**

```
runtime: nodejs10
env: standard
instance_class: F4_HIGHMEM
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 15
  min_instances: 0
  max_pending_latency: 10ms
  max_concurrent_requests: 1
```

Comment: This looks fine. The error may come from assigning point,  check if Puppeteer is starting successfully in logs. Are you using app engine standard? Please share app.yaml and also Dockerfile if flex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your use case on App Engine Standard:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const express   = require('express');
const fs        = require('fs');
var port        = process.env.PORT || 80;
const app       = express();

global.browser = null;

const setup = async function(){

  console.log("Initializing Puppeteer...")
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: [
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
      '--disable-dev-shm-usage=true',
      '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas=true',
      '--disable-gpu',
      ]
  });


browser.on('disconnected', setup);

}




app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  setup();
  console.log(`Started Puppeteer with pid ${browser.process().pid}`);
  res.status(200).send('Hello, world!').end();
});




// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {

  setup();
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
  console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
});
// [END gae_node_request_example]

module.exports = app;
```

[image]